# CriteriaUpdate Not yet implemented

Tags: java, hibernate

When I want to update an object using `criteriaUpdate` I get an exception

```
org.hibernate.NotYetImplementedFor6Exception: Not yet implemented
```

[image]

Comment: Is "Not yet implemented" not clear?  The code that implements that has not been written yet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a stable Hibernate release? As long as not all feature are fully to ported to Hibernate 6 (hence the `NotYetImplementedFor6Exception`) use Hibernate 5. This might be still the case. The migration should be simple if you are using JPA. Monitor the [API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/NotYetImplementedFor6Exception.html), as long as this internal class is not removed or the documentation updated, there might be some issues.